# Why this question was closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, suggested-edits, suspensions

I don't think that this question should be closed?

[A question on rigid body dynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/449938/a-question-on-rigid-body-dynamics)

This was closed as **unclear** but I think that I explained it at my best! What should I do to edit it?

If this is the case the questions are closed on this website then how can we leave this website completely?

Comment: I don't think downvoting is required!This is the only reason people are leaving this website.

Comment: Votes on the meta sites work a little differently to the main sites. Downvotes don't necessarily mean that a question is bad, or that an answer is wrong. They can also be used to indicate that people disagree with the opinions expressed in the question or answer.

Comment: I just had a quick look at your question, and it looks a bit unclear to me, and it looks like you're asking a couple of questions that are only loosely related. Please don't do that, try to focus on a single clear specific question. BTW, telling people to "Answer as fast as possible" is considered rude on Stack Exchange sites, and is likely to attract downvotes, and to create a negative impression on people who are deciding to cast close-votes.

Comment: How can I completely leave this website?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/

Comment: The question is quite unclear.  Is it about friction or angular momentum?  BTW the title is terribly non-descriptive and not useful if someone wishes to find your question.  It also doesn’t help clarity that you admit there are two questions.

Comment: You know I am banned to ask questions so I post them collectively there.

Comment: If this is a way around a question ban then you are not helping yourself.

Comment: But what should I  do I have so many questions to ask.

Comment: Wait ‘til the ban expires perhaps?  There are reasons as to why you were banned...

Comment: For that matter, there are two unrelated questions in this post as well: 1) How can I improve my question? 2) How do I leave this website?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the version that was closed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/dbec999f-6fa6-4876-9c36-707e3ab6cf17/view-source), you have two questions that you're asking:

1. What is the intuition for angular momentum of a point mass relative to a inertial point?
2. I am confused that at the same time the static friction helps in pure rolling by operating in direction opposite to wheels motion as well as it provides the car the required centripetal acceleration by operating towards the centre. How is it possible?

These are two separate questions. The first isn't clear what "intuition" you seek and what it is you understand. The best we can tell you is what a textbook might say, so you need to clarify what it is that you don't understand and would like further details on.

The second is probably a duplicate of other questions asked in this site (haven't looked to be sure, but it looks like queries I've seen before). It's also not clear how this question relates to the previous one.

You've already removed the second part, so no need to further worry about that. In order to get the question reopened, you need to explain what it is you *do* understand about angular momentum & how you *don't* see the connection to the relative inertial point.

Note also that stating "Answer as fast as possible!" is generally not well received, and often results in downvotes. We all here *volunteer* our time to answering questions, your want of a rapid response seems to not care and/or respect the volunteer nature of this service.

> If this is the case the questions are closed on this website then how can we leave this website completely?

Well, the most basic option is to just not come back to this site. If you also want to delete your account (an irreversible process), follow [these instructions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

Comment: Hi Kyle Kanos I am a Indian and my English is not good I think that you all consider my statements in another way but I never disrespected anyone.